# Significato di "sporgersi su" (L'amica geniale)

Tags: word-meaning

Nell'ultimo capoverso del quarto volume della serie "L'amica geniale", cioè nella *Storia della bambina perduta*, di Elena Ferrante ho trovato questa frase che mi lascia perplesso proprio alla fine di lunga lettura:

> A differenza che nei racconti, la vita vera, quando è passata, si
>   sporge non sulla chiarezza ma sull'oscurità.

Qualcuno può spiegarmi il senso di questa espressione "sporgersi su ql.co"? Credo che sia necessario conoscere il contesto della frase in questione, ovvero la storia intera, quindi inviterei a rispondere soprattutto chi ha letto il libro. Comunque qui sotto cito l'intero capoverso:

> Sono salita in ascensore, mi sono chiusa nel mio appartamento. Ho
>   esaminato le due bambole con cura, ne ho sentito l'odore di muffa, le
>   ho disposte contro i dorsi dei miei libri. Nel constatare che erano
>   povere e brutte mi sono sentita confusa. A differenza che nei
>   racconti, la vita vera, quando è passata, si sporge non sulla
>   chiarezza ma sull'oscurità. Ho pensato: ora che Lila si è fatta vedere
>   così nitidamente, devo rassegnarmi a non vederla più.

Comment: Scusa, non mi è chiaro il tuo dubbio. Conosci il significato di “sporgersi”, vero? Protendersi, affacciarsi, più o meno. Concretamente, uno può affacciarsi da una finestra e sporgersi sul cortile, sul vuoto, su un paesaggio incantevole o su qualsiasi altra cosa ci sia fuori dalla finestra. Qui lo stesso viene detto metaforicamente della vita. Ma forse non ho capito la tua domanda.

Comment: grazie per il commento. Infatti non riesco a afferrare il senso della "la vita (personificata come un soggetto) si sporge sulla chiarezza o sull'oscurità". O semplicemente: che vuol dire "sporgersi sulla chiarezza/oscurità" concretamente?

Comment: Per esempio, "un uccello che si sporge su una pozzanghera" lo riesco a immaginare benissimo, forse l'animale sta per bere l'acqua. Ma della "vita che si affaccia sulla chiarezza" non riesco a immaginare bene. So che si tratti, probabilmente, di un'espressione per figurare un concetto astratto, ma non riesco a cogliere il senso.

Comment: Capisco, ma a questo punto mi chiedo quanto sia una domanda sulla lingua italiana e quanto invece di interpretazione letteraria.

Comment: hai ragione... diciamo che si tratti di entrambi. Ma mi aiuta molto che hai espresso la tua opinione che sostiene che il significato del verbo "sporgersi" in questo caso non sia niente di particolare ma proprio quello del significato principale: affacciarsi o protendersi su qualcosa. Perché la mia paura è sempre che mi sfugga qualche sfumatura particolare che non riesco a trovare su dizionari.

Comment: Penso che abbia a che vedere con l'ultima frase: "Lila si è fatta vedere così nitidamente" (chiarezza), "non vederla più" (oscurità). Credo sia un po' come dire che, quando la vita vera passa, di solito rimangono gli aspetti oscuri e non quelli chiari. L'autrice usa "sporgersi" per ottenere una frase poetica.

Comment: Grazie, può darsi che come dici tu. Mi ci rifletterò su.